# Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Excel', The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I got an error while working on asp.net web application. My website was building properly with no errors but while I was trying to publish it I was getting an error like below;

> **Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Excel, version=1.5.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=null' or one of its dependencies. the parameter is incorrect.**

I tried to clear the soultion many times and also closed the solution and reopen but the issue still persists.

Any one please suggest anything how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Why are you trying to interop with Excel in ASP .NET? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: That was in my project; as this was referenced previously......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have referenced corrupted dll, try to clean the temp folder

`C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

AND

`C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files`

Comment: C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files

clearing this worked fine for me; thanks bro....

Answer (score 0):

Since you currently reference interop assemblies for 2010, you must install PIA for 2010 http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3508.

Only after you update your references in Visual studio to use 2007 interop assemblies, you can go on with http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18346

Answer (score 0):

**C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files**

Clearing this helped me in publishing my project without any kind of error.